# Kafka Connect failed to start

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I installed kafka confluent oss 4.0 on a fresh linux centos 7 but kafka connect failed to start.

Steps to reproduce :

```
 - Install Oracle JDK 8
 - Copy confluent-4.0.0 folder on opt/confluent-4.0.0
 - Run /opt/confluent-4.0.0/confluent start
```

Result :

```
Starting zookeeper
zookeeper is [UP]
Starting kafka
kafka is [UP]
Starting schema-registry
schema-registry is [UP]
Starting kafka-rest
kafka-rest is [UP]
Starting connect
\Kafka Connect failed to start
connect is [DOWN]
```

Error Log (connect.stderr) :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/confluent/connect/storage/StorageSinkConnectorConfig
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:54)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.getPluginDesc(DelegatingClassLoader.java:279)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanPluginPath(DelegatingClassLoader.java:260)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanUrlsAndAddPlugins(DelegatingClassLoader.java:201)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.registerPlugin(DelegatingClassLoader.java:193)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initLoaders(DelegatingClassLoader.java:153)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.<init>(Plugins.java:47)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.main(ConnectDistributed.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.confluent.connect.storage.StorageSinkConnectorConfig
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:62)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 22 more
```

Additional informations :

Java version :

```
java version "1.8.0_151"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode
```

Centos version :

```
centos-release-7-4.1708.el7.centos.x86_64
```

[Edit : 30/11/2017]
Editing plugin.path variables in every properties files didn't fix the problem.

List of files containing 'plugin.path' variable :

```
./etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-distributed.properties:84:plugin.path=/opt/confluent-4.0.0/share/java
./etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-standalone.properties:51:plugin.path=/opt/confluent-4.0.0/share/java
./etc/kafka/connect-distributed.properties:95:plugin.path=/opt/confluent-4.0.0/share/java
./etc/kafka/connect-standalone.properties:50:plugin.path=/opt/confluent-4.0.0/share/java
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With Confluent 4.0.0, classloading isolation with [plugin.path](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/userguide.html#installing-plugins) is enabled by default for Kafka Connect.

When you install Confluent Platform from `deb` or `rpm` packages the default location of your `plugin.path` is known beforehand.

However, when you download and extract the `zip` or `tar.gz` archive of Confluent Platform somewhere in your filesystem, it's set to:

`plugin.path=share/java`

This is a relative path, because when you download Confluent Platform as an archive (`zip` or `tar.gz`), the location where you extract the archive is not known (in your example above it's `/opt/confluent-4.0.0/`).

The CLI or Connect's bin scripts will be able to guess this location if you run it from the directory where you extracted Confluent platform:

For instance, in the example above:

`cd /opt/confluent-4.0.0`

`./bin/confluent start`

In order for you to be able to start Connect from any directory within your filesystem, given that the `bin` directory for Confluent Platform is in your `PATH`, you will need to set the property `plugin.path` to the absolute path location of your plugins:

To use Confluent CLI edit:

`etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-distributed.properties`

and set your `plugin.path` appropriately (here: `plugin.path=/opt/confluent-4.0.0/share/java`)

For the regular bin scripts edit:

`./etc/kafka/connect-distributed.properties`

and

`./etc/kafka/connect-standalone.properties`

and set your `plugin.path` as above (again, in your example: `plugin.path=/opt/confluent-4.0.0/share/java`).

Comment: Thanks for your time and your answer. I edited all properties files within ./etc ,destroyed the confluent instance and restarted everything with ./bin/confluent start but nothing change, all services are UP but connect is still down with the same error.

Comment: List all files with plugin.path  : 
./etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-distributed.properties:84:plugin.path=/opt/confluent-4.0.0/share/java

./etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-standalone.properties:51:plugin.path=/opt/confluent-4.0.0/share/java

./etc/kafka/connect-distributed.properties:95:plugin.path=/opt/confluent-4.0.0/share/java

./etc/kafka/connect-standalone.properties:50:plugin.path=/opt/confluent-4.0.0/share/java

Comment: Is there a symbolic link from `share/java/kafka-connect-s3/storage-common` to `../kafka-connect-storage-common` that is valid? Similar link should be present in `kafka-connect-hdfs`.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you used the tar installation (rather than the Docker image approach). Long story short, you need to be inside of the Confluent distribution, in my example,  confluent-6.1.0
[image: Not Working Vs. Working]
As shown in the screenshot, when you run the command *confluent local services start* in the root directory, Connect failed. And anything after that failure (e.g. ksqlDB, Control Center etc.) didn't even get a chance to start.
When you run the same command inside of confluent-6.1.0, everything worked out.