# Kafka FileSteamSource Connect Error

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to read a simple text /tmp/my-test.txt using kafka connect. Below is my file source properties file.

```
connect-file-source.properties

name=local-file-source
connector.class=FileStreamSource
tasks.max=1
file=/tmp/my-test.txt
topic=my-connect-test
```

Error that I get while starting the connector worker: `org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches FileStreamSource`

Do i need to install a FileStreamSource plugin in the kafka classpath. I read it comes bundled with the kafka.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you've installed Kafka Connect, you might need to specify the `plugin.path` in the worker's configuration.

Here's a related question: 
[Kafka Connect failed to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47555927/kafka-connect-failed-to-start)