# kafka connect failed to start (Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException)

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

Trying to install confluent platform in my macOS (11.2.3)
But the `connect` can not start. I using java 8 update 281.
Followed the suggestions of [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47555927/kafka-connect-failed-to-start) answer  but no luck.

```
Starting ZooKeeper
ZooKeeper is [UP]
Starting Kafka
Kafka is [UP]
Starting Schema Registry
Schema Registry is [UP]
Starting Kafka REST
Kafka REST is [UP]
Starting Connect
Error: Connect failed to start
```

error log in connect.log:

```
[2021-04-05 23:47:40,486] ERROR Stopping due to error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed:85)
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.nextSpi(KeyGenerator.java:340)
    at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.<init>(KeyGenerator.java:168)
    at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyGenerator.java:223)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedConfig.validateKeyAlgorithm(DistributedConfig.java:502)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedConfig.lambda$configDef$2(DistributedConfig.java:375)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef$LambdaValidator.ensureValid(ConfigDef.java:1038)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef$ConfigKey.<init>(ConfigDef.java:1159)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.define(ConfigDef.java:152)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.define(ConfigDef.java:172)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.define(ConfigDef.java:211)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.define(ConfigDef.java:373)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedConfig.configDef(DistributedConfig.java:371)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedConfig.<clinit>(DistributedConfig.java:196)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.startConnect(ConnectDistributed.java:94)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.main(ConnectDistributed.java:79)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Can not initialize cryptographic mechanism
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.<clinit>(JceSecurity.java:93)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: The jurisdiction policy files are not signed by the expected signer! (Policy files are specific per major JDK release.Ensure the correct version is installed.)
    at javax.crypto.JarVerifier.verifyPolicySigned(JarVerifier.java:336)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.loadPolicies(JceSecurity.java:378)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.setupJurisdictionPolicies(JceSecurity.java:323)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.access$000(JceSecurity.java:50)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity$1.run(JceSecurity.java:85)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.<clinit>(JceSecurity.java:82)
    ... 15 more
```

Comment: I would try Java 11... But there's no security things enabled by default in Confluent Platform, so did you change anything? And anything against using Docker Compose since there, the JDK version is consistent to create a [mcve]?

Comment: I removed my jdk 8 and installed jdk 11 and problem solved.